# Save django CreateView in Python Shell

Tags: django, postgresql, django-generic-views, create-view

I'm trying to write a test for my CreateView view in django. As part fo the test, I want to create a new object through a CreateView class, though I'm unsure how to save the object through tests.py.

models.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length = 50,
    )
```

views.py

```
class MyCreateView(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
```

tests.py

```
from myapp.views import MyCreateView

m = MyCreateView()
m.name = 'John Doe'
# save object here
```

Neither m.save() nor m.submit() will work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/

It is well documented and shows how to test views and models.